# How to understand $k \otimes_R \alpha \cong k \oplus k$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $R = k[x, y]$, where $k$ is field. Then we have a projective resolution of $k$ :

> $$0 \longrightarrow R \stackrel{f}\longrightarrow R\oplus R \stackrel{g}\longrightarrow R \longrightarrow k \to 0 $$

where $f(r)=(-ry, rx), \,\,g(r_1, r_2)=r_1x + r_2 y$.

Take $\alpha = (x, y)$, which is an ideal of $R$. Then we can use the projective resolution and the short sequence $0 \rightarrow \alpha \rightarrow R \rightarrow k \rightarrow 0$ computing $\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(k, \alpha)$.
Hence we have

> $\operatorname{Tor}_{i-1}^R(k, \alpha) \cong \operatorname{Tor}_i^R(k, k)$.

In particular we have $\operatorname{Tor}_0^R(k, \alpha) \cong \operatorname{Tor}_1^R(k, k) \cong k \oplus k$.

Question:

1. How to understand $k \otimes_R \alpha \cong k \oplus k$?
2. How to compute  $\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(k, \alpha^n)$

I appreciate all your help.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "understand" in the first question. For 2., the minimal free resolution of $\alpha$ can be described explicitly. For instance, $\alpha_2$, the matrix representation of $f$ looks [x -y 0] [0 x -y]. For the general case, one needs to put more zeros and put x -y in the appropriate positions.

Comment: First, when you say "a projective resolution of $k$," I guess you've chosen the $R$-module structure on $k$ for which $x \cdot 1 = y \cdot 1 = 0$. For question 1, then, if you choose a basis for $\alpha$ consisting of $x$, $y$, $xy$, ..., then in the tensor product, $1 \otimes xy = x\cdot 1 \otimes y = 0 \otimes y$, and similarly for other monomials of degree bigger than 1. The elements $1 \otimes x$ and $1 \otimes y$ form a basis for $k \otimes_R \alpha$, so it is a two-dimensional vector space with a trivial $R$-action.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri thanks for your help. As you say, this R-module isomorphism is just the vector space's isomorphism ?

Comment: It's a vector space isomorphism combined with an analysis of the $R$-module structure on $k \otimes_R \alpha$.